# Accessing nested properties of a TileSet

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to access all the features of a specific tileset generated threw MapBoxStudio.

Reading the API doc I guess I should be able to get all the nested parameters from the method :
`map.querySourceFeatures(IdOfMyLayer);`

However, the output of this is empty.

```
map.querySourceFeatures('words');
```

Where 'words' is the ID of the layer I got from  `map.getStyle().layers`

I would expect to get access to the properties of this particular layer.
However, I get an empty result.

Sorry for the noob question but I am missing something crucial here in the way MapBox is working, any help from you would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? I'm not sure I know what you mean "all the nested parameters", or the "properties of this particular layer".

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access *all* the features of a tileset that you created in Studio, you should probably consider a different workflow. By definition, a tileset is a transformation of a dataset optimised for displaying a map, not querying.

If you use a Mapbox *dataset* rather than a *tileset*, you can access the whole dataset as a clean GeoJSON object - assuming it's small enough to load into the browser. Alternatively, you could create a GeoJSON by some other means, then upload it.

If `querySourceFeature()` is returning `[]`, then most likely no features have loaded in the current viewport (yet). Perhaps you need to trigger the call at a later time, when the source data has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now.
The proper way to retrieve all the features of a dataset is to use the DataSet API:

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-a-dataset

This is what I've done :

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/*****/{dataset_id}/features?limit=50&access_token=********',
            type:'GET',
            success:function(data){console.log(data)},
            error:function(error){console.log('ERROR')}
        })
```

With the {dataset_id} taken from mapboxStudio.

I can limit and store the variable to process the JSON response.
Thanks a lot :)